# Bootstrap 3 Vertical Align issue with grid sections containing input elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row that is split down into various columns and sub-columns. In the proper example there are several more inputs but I've removed them for clarity as they're not needed for this example.

```
        <form id="inputForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Primary Packaging:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="pack1Height" class="control-label">Height:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="pack1Height" class="form-control small text-right" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">mm</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label class="control-label">Vol:</label>
                    <label class="control-label">999</label>
                    <label class="control-label">cm<sup>3</sup></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/53vu25ad/ you can see the issue as "Primary Packaging" and "Vol: 999 cm3" are not vertically aligned within the row - they're top aligned.  Is there something I'm missing here?

(ps: On my form, the "height" label and the input element are on the same line, I have no idea why they're not in this jsfiddle, but it's not relevant to the question - I would still expect to see the two labels either side aligned vertically).

Answer (score 1):

Using bleeding-edge not-yet-released Bootstrap v3.2.1: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvrhulu/3vemz7Lj/)

The trick is to use a dummy `.form-control-static`:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Primary Packaging:</label>
        <p class="form-control-static">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well without using experimental bootstrap, the way I got around this was adding a simple custom class that matched the form-control element height of 34px.

By setting the row `line-height` to the same, it automatically valigns content.

```
.fixedRow {
    line-height: 34px;
}

<div class="row fixedRow">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <label class="control-label">Primary Packaging:</label>
     </div>
...
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53vu25ad/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53vu25ad/1/)

You may need to use the `.form-group` class for `.form-inline`

```
<form id="inputForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Primary Packaging:</label>
         </div>   
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="pack1Height" class="control-label">Height:</label>
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="pack1Height" class="form-control small text-right" />
            <span class="input-group-addon fw1">mm</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Vol:</label>
         <label class="control-label">999</label>
         <label class="control-label">cm<sup>3</sup></label>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well thanks for trying, but you've taken away the bootstrap grid which I need for spacing!  You've also left two extraneous divs in there at the end!  It has to be in the grid system as I showed, contained within a bootstrap "row" element.